# Averaging a summation in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following tables:

`test_results`

| id | course_id | student_id | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 2021 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 2021 |

`test_periods`

| id | result_id | period_index | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 10 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 9 |

and I'm trying to answer the following question: Given a `year` and a `course_id`, sum up the `value` column across all `student_id` for each `period_index`, and then average the summations across all periods. Using the example tables, getting the answer would be as follows:

1. Sum up the `value` column across all students: `period_index = 0` => `5 + 10 = 15` and `period_index = 1` => `7 + 9 = 16`
2. Average summations across all periods: `(15 + 16) / 2 = 15.5`

I tried achieving this using the following query:

```
SELECT AVG((SELECT SUM(p.value) FROM test_periods p WHERE p.result_id = r.id GROUP BY p.period_index))
FROM test_results r
```

But it gives me the following error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

**UPDATE**

There's one more thing that I forgot to mention is that both aggregate functions in the query above can be changed based on some variables, for example:

```
DECLARE @inner_agg_method NVARCHAR(3) = 'avg';
DECLARE @outer_agg_method NVARCHAR(3) = 'avg';


SELECT CASE
           WHEN @outer_agg_method = 'avg' THEN AVG((SELECT CASE
                                                               WHEN @inner_agg_method = 'avg' THEN AVG(p.value)
                                                               WHEN @inner_agg_method = 'max' THEN MAX(p.value)
                                                               ELSE -1 END
                                                    FROM test_periods p
                                                    WHERE p.result_id = r.id
                                                    GROUP BY p.period_index))
           WHEN @outer_agg_method = 'max' THEN MAX((SELECT CASE
                                                               WHEN @inner_agg_method = 'avg' THEN AVG(p.value)
                                                               WHEN @inner_agg_method = 'max' THEN MAX(p.value)
                                                               ELSE -1 END
                                                    FROM test_periods p
                                                    WHERE p.result_id = r.id
                                                    GROUP BY p.period_index))
           ELSE -1
           END
FROM test_results r
```

P.S. I'm using SQL Server 2019.

P.S. (2) for anyone who wants to test the code on their machine, you can execute the following queries to create and populate the tables as in the example above:

```
CREATE TABLE test_results
(
    id         INT PRIMARY KEY,
    course_id  INT NOT NULL,
    year       INT NOT NULL,
    student_id INT NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE test_periods
(
    id           INT PRIMARY KEY,
    result_id    INT NOT NULL,
    period_index INT NOT NULL,
    value        FLOAT,
    FOREIGN KEY (result_id) REFERENCES test_results (id)
)

INSERT INTO test_results
VALUES (0, 0, 2021, 0)
INSERT INTO test_results
VALUES (1, 0, 2021, 1)

INSERT INTO test_periods
VALUES (0, 0, 0, 5)
INSERT INTO test_periods
VALUES (1, 0, 1, 7)
INSERT INTO test_periods
VALUES (2, 1, 0, 10)
INSERT INTO test_periods
VALUES (3, 1, 1, 9)
```

Comment: Are you trying to get a single number (**15.5** in your example) or a table-like set of rows and columns?

Comment: @AnnL. A single number

Comment: Does the query in your update actually run? (The one with the inner and outer aggregation method control variables.)

Comment: It gives me the same error as the initial query. The thing is; after doing some reasearch, sql server cannot perform nested aggregates. I was wondering if there is a way to do it differently.

Comment: Do the two tables have any columns in common? In your example data, it doesn't look like they do, although @GordonLinoff's answer assumes `result_id` is in both tables.

Comment: Yes they do, `test_periods` references `test_results` using the `result_id` column.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to set up some kind of parameterized query engine in SQL, where people can control the calculation by passing in a "control flag" parameter. Solutions like that tend to be very brittle and a lot more work than they initially look like they will be. What is your use case?

Comment: @AnnL. I have a list of courses, each course has a duration of one year. A year is divided into periods. Every student in the course is evaluated at each period. To get the performance of each student, we use a property assigned to the course that tells us how to aggregate the results across periods (`@outer_agg_method`). To get the overall performance of the entire course, first, we need to aggregate the students' results using a course's property that tells us how (`@inner_agg_method`), and then we aggregate across periods like earlier.

Comment: How many different "aggregation methods" are there?

Comment: @AnnL. the `@inner_agg_method` has only one for now, which is the `sum`. The `@outer_agg_method` has three; we either take the average, sum, or the result associated with the last period.

Comment: I don't think that all this can be done with just one single query, esp with that "result associated with last period" in the mix. (Where is that stored? Or is it also calculated?) You might be able to do it with 2 or 3, picking the desired one based on `@outer_agg_method`.

Comment: But, I need to bow out for the night: it's too late in the evening where I am! I'll look in again tomorrow, if I can.

Comment: @AnnL. the last period can be figured out by using the `period_index`; the period with the maximum value is the last period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use conditional aggregate to find the value for the last period

```
select  avg_value           = avg(sum_value),
        sum_value           = sum(sum_value),
        last_period_value   = max(case when period_index = last_period 
                                       then sum_value end) 
from
(
    select  p.period_index, 
            sum_value   = sum(p.value),
            last_period = max(p.period_index) over()
    from    test_results r
            inner join test_periods p   on  r.id    = p.result_id
    group by p.period_index
) v
```

Comment: Nice! An elegant solution!

Answer (score 1):

This answers the original version of the question.

If I understand correctly, you can `join` the tables together and then aggregate.  Your final average is the sum of the value across all rows divided by the number of `period_index` values:

```
select r.year, r.course_id, 
       sum(p.value) / count(distinct p.period_index) as average
from test_results r join
     test_periods p
     on r.result_id = p.result_id
group by r.year, r.course_id
```

Comment: The query returns what I asked for exactly. There's one more thing that I forgot to mention in my question that the aggregate functions can change, for instance what if instead of `sum` I decided to use `max`. Is it still doable?

Comment: I updated my question to cover the change of aggregate functions.

Comment: You could add a fourth column to the query Mr. Linoff has provided, calculating a  value with `max` instead of `sum`, and use your inner and outer method flags to determine which one to reference in your final result.

Comment: @AnnL. Yeah that's right I could do that, but this would cover the part when I need to change the inner aggregate. How about if I wanted to change the outer one?

Comment: @m2008m1003m Well, that gets tricky, because you're not just swapping in a different aggregate function: you're actually doing the calculation (value / count) to get the average. I think I need to know more about your desired end result. I'll ask some more q in the question comments.